# Not including body in API request using Playwright

Tags: testing, request, automated-tests, playwright

I have problem with my API request. I try to send request using below method

```
async createRequest(method: string, endpoint: string, parameters?: object, body?: object) {
let request = null;
const browser = await chromium.launch();
const context = await browser.newContext({});
let bodyRequest = JSON.stringify(body);

try {
  request = await context.request[method.toLowerCase()](
    endpoint,
    {
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      params: this.convertObjectToKeyValue(parameters),
      body: bodyRequest });
} catch (error) {
  await browser.close();
  throw new Error('Invalid request: /' + method + ' ' + endpoint + ' \n error message: ' + error);
}
const responseBody = await request.json();
await browser.close();

return responseBody;
}
```

I checked if passing body is visible and it  and it's but when I'm still getting error 400. Also I see in server logs that request has lack of body. Do you have any idea what is wrong with that code?

Comment: solved, I had change    body: bodyRequest }); on data: bodyRequest });

Comment: Please post a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

According to Playwright [API-Tests Docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/api-testing)
you should use the `data` argument instead of `body`.
Example:

```js
test("should create a bug report", async ({ request }) => {
  const newIssue = await request.post(`/repos/${USER}/${REPO}/issues`, {
    data: {
      title: "[Bug] report 1",
    },
  });
  expect(newIssue.ok()).toBeTruthy();
});
```